# Unable to build SQL connection using Python server on Unix

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, unix, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server through Python. I've installed *pyodbc* library at my user location using the following command:

`! pip install pyodbc --user`

I'm running python on a unix server and trying to build the connection using the following string :

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
          'Server=server_name;'
          'Database=db;',user = 'user',password ='pwd')
```

I'm able to connect to SQL Server while running python on windows on my local machine.

I believe the error is due to the missing driver, I downloaded some jar files, though I'm not sure how to set it up and setting the path, etc.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Please include the version, e.g., "Ubuntu 18.04", "Debian 9", etc..

Answer (score 0):

go to the path

```
/etc/odbc.ini
```

and create your data source name with your credentials

```
Driver                  = your_installed_driver
Server                  = my_machine\SQLEXPRESS
User                    = my_domain\my_user
Password                = my_password
Database                = your_database
```

Comment: I don't have access to make changes in the given location. Is there a work around this?